# How to get another value from the selected dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have project's class

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

then, it's displayed using dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id,
    new SelectList(Model.Projects, "Id", "Name", Model.Id),
    "-- Select --",
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If I select a project, I can get the Id and Name, but how to get the description?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#id').change(function () {
            alert('id = ' + $('#Id').val() + ', name = ' + $('#Id :selected').text() + ', description = ' + ???);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would also generate some kind of -data-` attribute on the select list items, so where you are setting the `@class` make a new one somehow in there for `-data-description` and then pull it from there in your alert. I think that `DropDownListFor` should accept a dictionary as well as the anonymous object type. So that way I would imagine you can pass in the name of `data-description` as `new { data-description = "" }` is not valid c#

Comment: I try to use data attribute, like this `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id,
    new SelectList(Model.Projects, "Id", "Name", Model.Id),
    "-- Select --",
    new { @class = "form-control", @data_description = ? })` but I don't know how to set data_description, could you send the sample code?

Comment: Sorry i cant give a ful answer, have not used MVC in a while. I think if my memory serves me well, you need to iterate over `Model.Projects` and create `new SelectListItem` instead of using the `new SelectList(` approach. If you can iterate over each select list item, maybe then you can set the description correctly.

Comment: oh I see, thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways

1. If list of projects are very large you will have to create API and use ajax to get a description.
2. In javascript get list of project from model and find a description

```
<script>

var projects = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Projects));
console.log(JSON.stringify(projects)); //only for test
 
$(function () {

        $('#id').change(function () {
 
    let id= $('#Id').val();
    let description = null;
     let name = null;
   
projects.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.Id === id) {
      name= item.Name;
      description= item.Description;
     break;
    }
});
    alert('id = ' + id + ', name = ' + name + ', description = ' + description);
        });
        
  }         
</script>
```

Comment: This also works, thank you

Comment: You are very welcome